# Understanding shared reference for lists and tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, cpython

I have list objects `a` and `b` which look as below:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3]
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
```

Output1:

```
1549645638528
1549650497792
```

Similarly, I have tuple objects `a1` and `b1` which look as below:

```
a1 = (1, 2, 3)
b1 = (1, 2, 3)
print(id(a1))
print(id(b1))
```

Output2:

```
1549643421120
1549643421120
```

Please help me understand why `a1` and `b1` are referencing to the same memory location?

And, why `a` and `b` are pointing to the different memory location?

Comment: The root cause is that tuples are immutable while lists are mutable.

Comment: There's no language-level reason here. The fact that `a1` and `b1` reference the same object is entirely an implementation detail of the CPython interpreter. Other implementations are free to handle that code differently.

Comment: @Learningisamess that's what *allows* the interpreter to make this optimization but it doesn't need to.

Comment: Why would you expect `a is b`? That doesn't make any sense to me. But here's an existing question that covers it: [Why Python allocates new id to list, tuples, dict even though having same values?](/q/35477813/4518341) (Note that the title implies that tuples always get a new ID, but that's not necessarily true, as you've demonstrated.)